# Replace a a column of values with a column of vectors in pandas

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I'm using python pandas to organize some measurements values in a DataFrame. 
One of the columns is a value which I want to convert in a 2D-vector so let's say the column contains such values:

```
 col1
 25
 12
 14
 21
```

I want to have the values of this column changed one by one (in a for loop):

```
for value in values:
    df.['col1'][value] = convert2Vector(df.['col1'][value])
```

So that the column `col1` becomes:

```
 col1
 [-1. 21.]
 [-1. -2.]
 [-15. 54.]
 [11. 2.]
```

The values are only examples and the function `convert2Vector()` converts the angle to a 2D-vector.

With the `for`-loop that I wrote it doesn't work .. I get the error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Which I can understand.

So the question is: How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That exception comes from the fact that you want to insert a `list` or `array` in a column (`array`) that stores `int`s. And `array`s in Pandas and NumPy can't have a "ragged shape" so you can't have 2 elements in one row and 1 element in all the others (except maybe with masking).

To make it work you need to store "general" objects. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : [25, 12, 14, 21]})
df.col1[0] = [1, 2]
# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

But this works:

```
>>> df.col1 = df.col1.astype(object)
>>> df.col1[0] = [1, 2]
>>> df
     col1
0  [1, 2]
1      12
2      14
3      21
```

Note: I wouldn't recommend doing that because `object` columns are much slower than specifically typed columns. But since you're iterating over the Column with a `for` loop it seems you don't need the performance so you can also use an `object` array.

---

What you should be doing if you want it fast is vectorize the `convert2vector` function and assign the result to two columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def convert2Vector(angle):
    """I don't know what your function does so this is just something that
    calculates the sin and cos of the input..."""
    ret = np.zeros((angle.size, 2), dtype=float)
    ret[:, 0] = np.sin(angle)
    ret[:, 1] = np.cos(angle)
    return ret

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : [25, 12, 14, 21]})
>>> df['col2'] = [0]*len(df)
>>> df[['col1', 'col2']] = convert2Vector(df.col1)
>>> df
       col1      col2
0 -0.132352  0.991203
1 -0.536573  0.843854
2  0.990607  0.136737
3  0.836656 -0.547729
```

Comment: thanks ! and then in order to use the vector's elements as real numbers do I need to convert them again ?

Comment: @BenJo You mean in the second case or the first case? In the second case it's easy: Just use `col1` where you need the first item and `col2` where you need the second item. If you were talking about the first case you could use `np.array(df.col1)` that converts it to a `rows x 2` array :)

Comment: The problem with the 2 columns solution is that I have then to import my dataframe in an database with defined number of columns so the first solution fits better. Specially if I still can access to the elemnts of the vectors as real numbers

Comment: @BenJo That also depends a bit on the database. You need to avoid that anything is stored as strings (then the conversion to numbers will be a bit annoying). But if it can store lists of numbers then you're fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should call a first order function like `df.apply` or `df.transform` which creates a new column which you then assign back:

```
In [1022]: df.col1.apply(lambda x: [x, x // 2])
Out[1022]: 
0    [25, 12]
1     [12, 6]
2     [14, 7]
3    [21, 10]
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

In your case, you would do:

```
df['col1'] = df.col1.apply(convert2vector)
```

Comment: `apply` on a `Series` is just as slow as a `for`-loop. In this case it's even slower because it has a layer of indirection (the `lambda`). But still a good answer, just needs a bit more of clarification. :)

Comment: @MSeifert That was stupid of me. The lambda isn't needed!

Comment: That wasn't what I meant. `apply` on a `Series` is just a better hidden antipattern. But it's a bit better without `lambda` :D

Comment: @MSeifert Ah, yes. When you say it like that.